# Better way save password in mysql which can be decrypted also using php

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, encryption

I am currently using  md5 function to encrypt my password and save to mysql db which can not be decrypted.

Now my user want that when they forgot password, they should get same (old) password instead of new password.

So my question is that what should i use to encrypt my password and store in mysql Database.
And i can decrypt that password also.

i am running on php and mysql.

Thanks

Avinash

Comment: Think twice before implementing this method... you're going to be introducing more security problems than it solves.

Comment: A password you can turn back into its original value is BAD. Don't do it.

Comment: Recently, password breaches are becoming VERY common. If you don't have the user passwords in your database, they can't be stolen as easily. http://news.google.com/news?q=password+breach

Comment: MD5 is likely fine.  What is important is salting etc.

Comment: Why would they want to recover the same password they already forgot -at least- once?

Comment: MD5 is NOT fine. In fact, it is cryptographically broken and should not be used for any security related stuff any more.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't do that...

First, use something better than md5. Then create a way to "reset" the password, but never a way to actually retreive the password from the db...

That will make your app less secure, but maybe even worse; you and your users will have a problem if your data gets stolen! Someone is going to have a database with usernames and passwords of all your users!

Comment: +1 for password reset. Is there something wrong with md5() and if it is, what are examples of something better? I'm genuinely interested myself.

Comment: @Pekka: Have a read of the WP article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5  MD5 is a great means of hashing files for integrity checks and such, but no longer an up-to-date cryptographic tool.

Comment: @Pekka: This: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerability 
Something better: check out SHA-512, for a start.

Answer (score 5):

Encrypting instead of hashing means that you have to store the decrypt key, which means reduced security for your app. Reset their password, and send them the new one.

Comment: The only right way to go. The user's password is none of our (site owners' and programmers') business.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that, it will compromise your security! The whole idea of one way encryption is that if your database is hacked you won't face the problem that all your users passwords will be known alongside with their email addresses!

Answer (score 0):

how about [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) or [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to do that you better can create a way to reset the password

Comment: Why post a redundant answer minutes after code-zoop's? Just vote his/hers up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an internal private site with no security issues, just store passwords with XOR 0xAD each byte. Otherwise, reset is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

- create dynamic salts ( 2, one 'permanent' to mix with the password before hashing / crypting, other one dynamic, changing every time user logs in  );

  ```
  $dynamicSalt = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
  {    
      $dynamicSalt .= chr(rand(33, 126)); 
  }
  ```
- never save passwords in any manner that can help you 'decode' them later, it's not up to you to retrieve original password but to let users reset it

If you really need to save the original passwords, create a database account with WRITE permissions only and store it in some other database ( on another server ? ).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to store the password in such a way that it is still recoverable without either

1) storing the decryption key in your code/data (which rather defeats the purpose of hashing/encrypting the password)

2) encrypting the password using public/private key encryption the routing the recovery through som sort of semi-manual process where the password can be recovered.

The simplest solution is to require your users to provide/maintain a current email address and rely on the security of that to provide a new password on request.

C.